# ConnectionString property gets cleaned up at the end of the "using" statement

Tags: c#-4.0, connection-string, session-variables, using-statement

In Session_Start method of Global.asax I store a sql connection in a session variable. Then the sql connection is used in a using statement:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)Session[AppConstants.DB_CONNECTION])
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.USR_SP_IsThisAValidUser", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        conn.Open();
        //do some work
    }
}
```

When exiting the using statement the connection string property of the sql connection stored in the Session gets cleaned up. Maybe I'm wrong here, but I thought that only the **conn** should be disposed.
It causes the "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." error when the above code is called again.

Comment: The connection string property *is* part of the connection object. It's not clear why you're storing a SQL connection in the session at all... why aren't you just opening a connection each time you use it, as normal?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm modifying an existing app not developed by me. To go your way I'd have to redesign the whole code.

Comment: Well fundamentally it's a bad idea to store the connection in the session. It really *shouldn't* be too hard to change it not to do that... seeing as you should be disposing of the connection after each use, why not either store the connection string in the session, or if it's the same connection string app-wide, store *nothing* in the session, and just change the places where you currently retrieve it from the session? It should be a fairly simple change.]

Comment: @JonSkeet, you're right. I'll change it. But still I'm wondering why it's happening like this :)

Comment: It's just part of disposing of the connection.